# replacing the ith occurrence of H in a string in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

i try to use the following command to replace the 3th occurrence of H in the string "AHBHCHEFHDGA"

```
gsub("(?=H).{3}[H]", ".","AHBHCHEFHDGA" , perl = TRUE)
```

But the output is "AHBHC.DGA" which is replacing the whole "HEFH", could someone provide a right solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
sub("((?:[^H]*H){2}[^H]*)H", "\\1.","AHBHCHEFHDGA")
## -> [1] "AHBHC.EFHDGA"
```

See the [R demo](http://ideone.com/u2Cwxi)

**Details**:

- `((?:[^H]*H){2}[^H]*)` - a capturing group #1 capturing:

  - `(?:[^H]*H){2}` - exactly 2 occurrences of 0+ chars other than `H` followed with `H` and then
  - `[^H]*` - 0+ chars other than `H`
- `H` - a literal `H`

With the `\\1` backreference the value stored in the captured group #1 is put back into the replacement result.

With `sub`, only 1 search and replace operation is performed, no need in `gsub`.

No need in a PCRE regex, either, a TRE pattern works well, too.